# unreal engine 4.22.3 crushes when i manipulate(rotate,scale) 3d mesh

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

i am a complete noob with unreal engine ,
i am using **parrot os** and unreal engine was **compiled from source**

unreal engine **crushes** when i click on **rotate or scale** button
after selecting a 3d model in game preview
i did not get to coding yet and did not change anything
:(
[crash log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S5V7s.png)

i tried re making a project
but it always crashes as soon as i try to manipulate
altho
manipulating with sidebar works fine [right of game preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4PfTf.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can imagine is that there's something wrong in the object constructor that you're moving. The constructor method is called every time you move or rotate the object and if you're modifying game state or game actors or some other prohibited functions in the constructor, the engine will crash, especially if you're not playing. Try to check the blueprint of that object and the constructor method (it's the section called "Construction script") and try to deatach the pins from the first node on the left.

If you didn't write code and you didn't import any plugin with blueprint than this is not your problem and I don't know how to help with so little informations.